# How to check if the change in nested data is permissible

Tags: json, laravel, ember.js, traversal, lumen

We have a nested JSON structure in our web app on the frontend like Rows > Columns > Elements > Rows > Columns > Elements ...

We also have an API call which sends the entire data as JSON to backend.

In the backend we have a set of several permissions, like column size change, row background change, element ordering change, etc that are permitted or denied for various types of users.

We want to identify in the backend if the change of the nested structure is permissible.

Example 1 [Update data]:

The user has CHANGED the size of a 'Column', where the size is represented as a property in 'Column' object.

or

Example 2 [Remove/Add data]:

The user has removed/added an 'Element' from a 'Column'.

We know that we can do full traverse on the entire tree, and understand if the change was permissible or not, but we are looking for a better and faster, resource saving solution for concurrent connections and many users/big trees.

---

This question seems to be general for different technologies, but I want to let you know that we are using Laravel / Lumen / Dingo in the backend & Ember.js on the frontend.

Thanks for reading and helping :)

Comment: One interesting question is how you *store* the data. Because, if you store it in a relational database, everything has an unique id. Use that.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to not send the entire JSON to the server, but to instead send json patch (see http://jsonpatch.com/).  Then on the server, have rules that affectively hash the paths in the patch to permissions.  In other words, since you are only sending the change and not the entire JSON, the need to parse the entir

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, Rouben. But in this case, can we be 100% sure that after some operations, if the data on the backend and on the frontend will always be 100% the same and identical? How we can handle a case, where one of the calls was denied by the backend during one of the operations :)

Comment: One thing you can do is maintain revision of a given document on the server.  When a patch is generated on the client, the revision for which it was created is added as part of the payload.  If the server receives a patch for which it is out of sync, you can then go about handling that case (in that case, ask the client to send the entire JSON and recompute...).

Comment: Hi Rouben.

As I understand we can have some hash of a document on frontend at the moment of the backend call and send it with the patch, backend will run the patch calculate the hash and check if those hashes are equal ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a API for returning permissions (have model `Permission`).

Then check for that permission for any actions you need in frontend by using [ember-can](https://github.com/minutebase/ember-can).

By this, you can ensure that when you send back data for updating from front to back, it is complying the permissions defined in backend and no need for many back n forth

Comment: But user can modify this permissions whenever they are already in frontend side right ? This might be not secure, so the permissions still need to be checked at backend part? Any thoughts ?

Comment: @ArmeniaH Yes absolutely you should check it in backend too

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have type for each change. For example column change is ----> colChange(or simpleChange). Send the type of change with json. Permission can be checked by change type. Also there can be groups of change types and permission can be sat to groups. In case if you don't send data for each change there must be stack of user changes(push type of change into stack on each user change). Send that stack with json to backend .

Comment: Vazg but the problem is that we can't trust the change type which came from frontend

Comment: You can trust why not? If There is not access to that Variable , nobody can change it,why you won't trust? Also you can keep info encrypted, to have secure info.

Comment: User can always change what comes form frontend :) its not safe
encryption still will be done in frontend, so its not secure too